# Evitar que una subcarpeta redirija a un subdominio

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirección

He añadido un nuevo subdominio en el servidor, de modo que la dirección ha quedado: subdominio.dominio.org. El problema es que el subdominio coincide con una carpeta de WordPress que ya existía, es decir dominio.org/subdominio/, y está redirigiendo automáticamente al nuevo subdominio, que además tiene instalado otro gestor, en este caso phpBB.

El mayor problema es que WordPress está instalado en public_html, y el subdominio tiene su carpeta de instalación allí.

¿Hay alguna forma de evitarlo? He buscado soluciones, pero todas las preguntas van al lado contrario: redireccionar de una subcarpeta a un subdominio, cuando yo lo que quiero es precisamente evitarlo y que esa subcarpeta quede en WordPress, sin redirecciones.

Comment: Al final lo he solucionado por la vía rápida, pues ni tan siquiera modificando el script path del servidor en phpBB, lograba nada. Primero he renombrado directamente la carpeta de "subdominio" a "phpbb" (para que no coincida con nada que se parezca en WordPress). Luego, en cPanel, he modificado la ruta de Document Root a "public_html/phpbb" y listo. No es la respuesta a la pregunta, pero funciona.

Comment: Sí. Hay forma, pero deberías publicar tu `.htaccess` para poder responderte. De lo contrario, cualquier posible respuesta podría romper alguna funcionalidad en tu sitio.